# In Dart, can 'dynamic' use methods of any data type?

Tags: dart, object, dynamic

In Dart, can 'dynamic' use methods of any data type?

I learned that variables declared as Object can only use .toString().
Since dynamic doesn't do type checking on variables,
can I use methods of any data type like .length or else?

Comment: You can call `.length` on a dynamic typed variable, but if the variable is a value of a type that does not have a `.length` getter method then it will throw an exception at runtime.